# SSIS issue with one specific Excel file and field brining in NULLs instead of values

Tags: excel, ssis

We have an Excel (XLSX) file that comes in weekly. One of the columns is "Card Number" its formatted as "General" and has badge numbers which all happen to be numeric.

Most of the values show up like this with the green mark and a message that says "The number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe"

[image]

All files are like this and all except for one import those values as-is just fine.
However, with one of the files which appears identical to all others most of the values in the import show up as NULL. Only ones that come through are the few records that don't have that green mark / message in Excel.

I have no idea what is wrong since it works for 99.9% of all others files which to me appear identical. They also have these values with green mark/message and are formatted as General.

In SSIS that field is coming in as DT_WSTR (255) and going into nvarchar (255) field in SQL.
Excel Source in SSIS is this:
**Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=\removed\source\file.xlsx;Extended Properties="EXCEL 12.0 XML;HDR=YES";**

Looking for some ideas or advise because I am stumped especially since this is happening with 1 out of 100+ files which are exported from same source in same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and successfully verified it.
Added **IMEX=1** to the end of the Excel connection string.

Found the explanation and solution here:
https://bageshkumarbagi-msbi.blogspot.com/2016/03/imex-1-extended-properties-in-ssis.html